# Design pattern and UML

Tags: design-patterns, uml

Can someone send me an article or a book where i can find how to use design patterns inside UML class diagrams?  Extra points for references having a case study and a summary about how to use design patterns throughout the UML class diagram.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with [Martin Fowler's PEAA book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321127420). Then read [GoF Design Patterns](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201633612).

Answer (score 5):

Check out the paper design patterns in UML:

http://citeseer.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download;jsessionid=0BD206579FFCD3CB04CEE65D99F391A1?doi=10.1.1.1.3297&rep=rep1&type=pdf

and a useful link here:

http://www.developer.com/design/article.php/3309461/Using-Design-Patterns-in-UML.htm

If you are looking for a book, try Applying Design Patterns and UML

[http://www.amazon.com/Applying-UML-Patterns-Craig-Larman/dp/0137488807](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0137488807)